# Link custom object to contact object on mobile number column

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field, lookup-field

I have a custom object which contains the mobile number of the users. I want to link this custom object to contact object on the mobile number.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. You need to show some research if you want the Community's assistance. You should read up on lookup fields and external ids

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is link the custom object record to a field on the contact record, then you simply need to create a custom field on the Contact object with the standard lookup relationship type that links to a phone number custom object record. But that's simple enough that I don't believe that's what you're asking.

If you're talking about creating a URL link to a custom object on the standard mobile phone number field of the contact object, then I'm pretty sure you can't do that since we cannot modify the data type of an existing standard field (which would be required for this).